# Fix EXIF orientation Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, exif

How can I fix the EXIF orientation in Angular 2?
I am loading an image from mobile and I need to fix the orientation.

I have tried the solution for this post: [Component inputs by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361770/component-inputs-by-reference) 
but FileReaderEvent type is not recognised by typescript, EXIF does not exist, and I can't access to the imageRotateDegrees, ImageExifRotation... properties.

This is my code:

`imageChange(input){
     if (input.files.length > 0) {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
            // Create a FileReader
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var self = this;
            reader.onload = function (e: any) {
                    img.onload = function() {
                           var resizedImg = self.resize(img);
                           self.model.base64Image = resizedImg;
                           self.picture = resizedImg;
                    }
                    img.src = e.target.result;
            } 
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0])
      }
}`

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found an Angular library for the problem https://github.com/bergben/ng2-img-max#readme and made it work for me with the following code:

```
initInputChangeListener() {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('imageFileInput');
    if (fileInput) {
        fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e: any) => {
            if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {

                const fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = () => {

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.base64Image = fileReader.result; 
                        // not sure if you need this
                        // but i had problems without this line of code
                    });

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        let myImage: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
                        myImage.src = fileReader.result;

                        this.ng2ImgMaxService.getEXIFOrientedImage(myImage)
                            .then(result => {
                                console.log('received getEXIFOrientedImage result');

                                let canvas = 
                                    <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                                let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                                let ratio = result.width / result.height;
                                let w = result.width - 100;
                                let h = (w / ratio);
                                canvas.width = w;
                                canvas.height = h;

                                context.drawImage(result, 0, 0, w, h);
                                let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    console.log('updating the image...');
                                    this.base64Image = dataUrl;
                                });


                            }, error => {
                                console.warn(error);
                            });
                    });
                };

                fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

inside from my template i used:

```
<img [src]="base64Image" />
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>
```